# Separating back end and front end servers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a existing application that have separate front end and back end servers. Both are Rails server front end as well as back end.

Directory structure is same for both Rails servers with some major differences. Those are

- Front end doesn't have database.yml, migrations files and no models and back end doesn't have views.
- Contollers code or files are different.
- Routes and Gems are different.

Now the idea is that Front end will send request to back end for getting data in Json format.

Question - what is the best approach to accomplish this?

1) Is it a good idea to run two copies(Front and Back end) of Rails app on two servers and make calls between then POSTing/PUTting information via HTTP (or connecting to a remote db)?

2) Is it a good idea to use Rest client for this?

If someone can point to a good guide or reference for this that would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Using rails server for just rendering views is not a good idea, If you have already exposed JSON API (Restful APIs) from backend server.

As you mentioned that you are trying to develop **Three-Tier Architecture** using restful webservices. There are many front-end client technologies available for accomplishing your purpose.

**1. Angular2**

The second version of the AngularJS web framework. Angular 2 takes a web component-based approach to building powerful applications for the web. It is used along with TypeScript which provides support for ECMAScript 5, ECMAScript 6, and ECMAScript 7.

More Info: https://angular.io/

**2. ReactJS**

React is a JavaScript framework for building user interfaces. It uses a declarative paradigm that makes it easier to reason about your application and aims to be both efficient and flexible. React, initially developed internally at Facebook, has since been made open source where it continues to be developed and maintained by Facebook and the open source community.

More Info: https://facebook.github.io/react/

**3. Aurelia**

Aurelia is a next generation JavaScript client framework that leverages simple conventions to empower your creativity.

More Info: http://aurelia.io/

> There are lot more technologies available: [Polymer.js](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/),
>   [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/)

Hope that helps!